# while installing python in caffe i get the following error

Tags: ubuntu, caffe, openpose

After installing the latest version, I get this error:

```
pandas 0.23.4 has requirement python-dateutil>=2.5.0, but you'll have python-dateutil 1.5 which is incompatible. matplotlib 3.0.2 has requirement python-dateutil>=2.1, but you'll have python-dateutil 1.5 which is incompatible.
```

The same after having try to remove the latest version and installs version 1.5.

How to overcome this error?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What version of Python? How did you do the installing?

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.